# Suppose that $f$ is surjective and relation preserving. Then $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive iff $\mathcal{S}$ is reflexive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, relations, problem-solving

This is a problem about **relations** from *Proofs and Fundamentals* by Ethan D. Bloch that I’m having some doubts and I would really appreciate if you could guide me.

The problem starts with the following definition:

> **Definition:** Let $A,B$ be sets, and let $\mathcal{R}, \mathcal{S}$ be relations on $A$ and $B$, respectively. Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a map. We say that $f$ is **relation preserving** if and only if $xRy$ iff $f(x)Sf(y)$ for all $x, y \in A$.

After this we have the following result:

> **Result:** Suppose that $f$ is surjective and relation preserving. Then $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive, symmetric or transitive iff $\mathcal{S}$ is reflexive, symmetric or transitive (respectively).

I attempt to show the reflexive part. And I have the following:

> *Proof:* $\implies$. Suppose that $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive. By definition, we have that $aRa$ for all $a \in A$. Since $f$ is relation preserving, it follows that $f(a)Sf(a)$. Since $f$ is surjective, we know that for all $b \in B$, there existis an element $a \in A$ such that $b = f(a)$. From this we know that $f(a)Sf(a)$ for all $f(a) \in B$. Hence, by definition, $\mathcal{S}$ is reflexive.
>
> $\Longleftarrow$. Suppose that $\mathcal{S}$ is reflexive. By definition, we have that $bSb$ for all $b \in B$.

Although, I don’t know what the next step should be. How can I deduce that $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive?

Also, will the proof for the other two properties be similar to this one?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathcal{S}$ is reflexive, let $a\in A$, and let $b=f(a)$. Since $f$ is relation-preserving, $a\,\mathcal{R}\,a$ iff $f(a)\,\mathcal{S}\,f(a)$, i.e., iff $b\,\mathcal{S}\,b$. And $\mathcal{S}$ is reflexive, so $b\,\mathcal{S}\,b$, and therefore $a\,\mathcal{R}\,a$. Thus, $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive.

Yes, the other two properties can be proved in much the same fashion.

Comment: Sorry, I’m confused, does that prove the equivalence or just one of the implications?

Comment: @AirMike: I apologize: I obviously lost track of which direction needed to be proved and wrote down the wrong one. The two directions really are essentially the same argument, since the definition of *relation-preserving* is an *iff* definition, but I’ve gone back and fixed it to show the direction that you hadn’t done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! Now I understand that it’s because of the *iff* definition. So the argument looks extremely similar for both implications!

Comment: @AirMike: You’re very welcome! Yes, the differences between the two directions are mostly cosmetic, so to speak.

Comment: I was trying to prove for the symmetric and transitive properties and one thing came to me, I suspect that for these two properties, it is not necessary for $f$ to be surjective. Is this right?

Comment: @AirMike: You’ll still need surjectivity of $f$: if it’s not surjective, it tells you nothing about the behavior of $\mathcal{S}$ on $B\setminus f[A]$, so you could have failures of symmetry or transitivity on that part of $B$.

Comment: I see... I think I only used the fact that $f$ is surjective when I wanted to show the implication: “If $\mathcal{R}$ is *something*, then $\mathcal{S}$ is also *something*”

Comment: @AirMike: Yes, you need it in that direction, but for these properties you don’t need it in the other direction (though you get it for free if $\mathcal{S}$ is reflexive).

Comment: Because in that last case: $\mathcal{S}$ is reflexive, we are saying that $(\forall b \in B): b \mathcal{S} b$ and since $f$ is relation-preserving, the surjectivity will also follow from here, right?

Comment: @AirMike: Sorry: that parenthetical remark is nonsense as stated. What I was actually thinking and meant to say is that if $f$ isn’t surjective, $\mathcal{S}$ doesn’t actually have to be reflexive, transitive, or symmetric on all of $B$: it just has to be reflexive, transitive, or symmetric on $f[A]$. And reflexivity is no different from the other two in this respect. (*sigh* Doing too many things at once again.)

Comment: No problem (I fell that ahah). But now I got that idea! Thank you so much for this really helpful feedback! :)

Comment: @AirMike: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the *iff* part in the definition of a relation-preserving function. Also, this can be proven more easily by a chain of equivalences:

> \begin{align}
> \textrm{$R$ is reflexive} \ & \textrm{ iff } \ (\forall a)(a \in A \to aRa) \\
> \ & \textrm{ iff } \ (\forall a)(a \in A \to f(a)Sf(a)) \quad [\textrm{by definition of relation-preserving}] \\
> \ & \textrm{ iff } \ (\forall b)(b \in B \to bSb) \quad [\textrm{since $f$ is surjective}] \\
> \ & \textrm{ iff } \ \textrm{$S$ is reflexive.}
> \end{align}

And, if you're still not convinced of the third equivalence:

> Suppose $(\forall a)(a \in A \to f(a)Sf(a))$ and take $b \in B$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $a_b \in A$ such that $b = f(a_b)$, and hence $f(a_b)Sf(a_b)$ implies that $bSb$. So, it is also true that $(\forall b)(b \in B \to bSb)$.
> Now suppose $(\forall b)(b \in B \to bSb)$ and take $a \in A$. Since $f(a) \in B$ we have $f(a)Sf(a)$, and so, $(\forall a)(a \in A \to f(a)Sf(a))$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi(X,\mathcal X)$ be any statement about a relation $\mathcal X\subseteq X\times X$ that has the form
$$ \forall x_1\in X,\ldots,\forall x_n\in X\colon \psi(\mathcal X;x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$$
where $\psi$ is any logical formula with atoms of the form $x_i\mathrel {\mathcal X} x_j$.
Examples:

- Refexivity: $\forall a\in X\colon a\mathrel {\mathcal X} a$
- Symmetry:  $\forall a\in X, \forall b\in X\colon a\mathrel {\mathcal X} b\to b\mathrel {\mathcal X} a$
- Transitivity: $\forall a\in X, \forall b\in X,\forall c\in X\colon a\mathrel {\mathcal X} b\land b\mathrel {\mathcal X} c\to a\mathrel {\mathcal X} c$

Assume  $f\colon A\to B$ is onto and relation-preserving for $\mathcal R\subseteq A\times A$, and $\mathcal S\subseteq B\times B$. Then
$$\Phi(A,\mathcal R)\iff \Phi(B,\mathcal S).$$

*Proof.*
First assume $\Phi(A,\mathcal R)$. Let $y_1,\ldots, y_n\in B$. By surjectivity of $f$, there exist $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in A$ with $f(x_i)=y_i$. By assumption $\psi(\mathcal R; x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is true. By relation preserving, $\psi(\mathcal R; x_1,\ldots,x_n)\leftrightarrow\psi(\mathcal S; y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ (directly, per "atom", but the also as a whole). As the $y_i$ were arbitrary, we conclude $\Phi(B,\mathcal S)$.

The argument that  $\Phi(B,\mathcal S)$ implies  $\Phi(A,\mathcal R)$ is even more direct. $\square$

Comment: In your argument, $\psi$ will assume all those properties, right?

Comment: I think I just got it! Thank you so much, that was such a nice and clever argument!